# Алгоритм работы экспертной системы

Tags: алгоритм

Догадываюсь, что экспертная система, которая принимает от пользователя ответы "да"/"нет" работает по следующему принципу:

1. Есть список ответов.
2. Для каждого ответа есть набор утверждений,
   которые ему характерны
3. В каждом вопросе проверяется утверждение.
4. Если утверждение верно, из списка возможных ответов исключаются
   ответы, для которых не характерно это утверждение.
5. Если утверждение не верно, из списка возможных ответов исключаются ответы, для которых характерно это утверждение.

Тогда по какому принципу работает экспертная система с вариантами ответа "да"/"нет"/"не знаю"? Может есть еще какие-то варианты организации диалога с пользователем?

Comment: добавляются вероятности, и в конце выбирается вариант с наибольшей вероятностью

Comment: Гуглите по терминам "байесовский классификатор", "байесовская сеть".

Comment: @Grundy к утверждениям? В задаче они 100% по умолчанию